# More generic word for "flavor"

Tags: single-word-requests

At the supermarket:

**Correct**
*"Which flavor icecream should we get?"*

**Incorrect**
*"Which flavor of shampoo should I get?*

What word could I use to talk about a particular choice among a collection of different... well... "flavors"?

Comment: *Editions, variants*, and their synonyms. What research have you done and what did you find? *Flavours* work, too

Comment: *Choice, kind, style, brand* - you need to provide more information to narrow down the options. Did you look up a thesaurus, e.g. http://www.thesaurus.com?

Comment: It's perfectly understandable if you use the word "flavor" even when talking about some item that won't be tasted ;) for example, in programming, the term "regex flavor" is often used to refer to the version/edition/implementation/engine of the regular expression grammar/syntax.

Comment: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flavor definition 3.a. is pretty generic already

Comment: It depends on the type of information you’re trying to elicit. You could ask, “What type of shampoo should I get?” if you were looking for answers such as, “dandruff control” or “color protection” or “oily hair”. OR you could ask, “What brand of shampoo should I get?” If you were looking for answers like, “Pert” or “Head and Shoulders” or “Finesse”.  Of course, “What kind of shampoo should I get?” allows either type of answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Normally, I am looking to be more explicit and discerning about which specific word or phrase to express something about some one thing among a mass of vaguely related "stuff." In this regard, I find myself quite amused to be headed in a different direction.

Kind…

One way to get some response in a qualitative query involving the acquiring of specific goods requiring some manner of clarification before investing resources is to enquire, "What ***kind***?"

Answer (score 3):

I would probably opt for ***["type"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/type)***.

> something distinguishable as a variety

For example:

> 1. What type of ice cream is your favourite?
> 2. You bought shampoo? What type?
> 3. There were lots of types of beer to try.

Answer (score 0):

You could use **taste**.

[MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/taste)

> Individual preference

This includes both *gustation and liking.*

"Pick your taste from these shampoos/ice cream."

Comment: That’s not really how you use that word.  you could ask, “what’s your taste in ice cream?” and you might pick something *according to your taste(s).” But you don’t *pick your taste*

Comment: If you've ever tasted shampoo, you know it's something you don't want to taste ;)  "taste" in the way you use it could end up getting the desired information, but it's not quite used the way I'm looking for.